# Uninstalled python3 from Ubuntu 18.04, then reinstalled it. Now I can only log in to tty

Tags: ubuntu, python, repair, tty

I uninstalled python3 from Ubuntu 18.04, then reinstalled it. (I knew it was a bad idea). Hoping it would restore the ubuntu packages too.

Now I can only log in to tty. I don't have network access. ifconfig only shows lo. No eth0.
I'm guessing I removed the drivers. Need to get it running with GUI. Any help will be appreciated.

I have access to other PC's. This is on my HDD and I have an SSD with Windows on it.

Comment: From personal experience with (accidentally) removing system Python packages, I wouldn't bother and simply re-install the OS. You may try `sudo apt install python3-all` and `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I don't have network access. I'm trying to see if a USB wifi adapter would work. If nothing then I will have to backup and re-install the OS.

Comment: Use the solution from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1472292/ubuntu-18-black-screen-no-login-and-grub-changed-to-turquoise-debian-8#comment2219835_1472292), but first add a LiveUSB Ubuntu as package source to install offline. And start making regular backups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18 black screen (no login) and Grub changed to turquoise Debian 8](https://superuser.com/questions/1472292/ubuntu-18-black-screen-no-login-and-grub-changed-to-turquoise-debian-8)

Comment: I couldn't get the live-usb source to work. Ended up reinstalling Ubuntu. Thanks for the help though.